# Accessing the serial port in a portable class library in C#

Tags: c#, portable-class-library, uwp

I'm writing a UWP App in which I'm accessing the serial port via `Windows.Devices.SerialCommunication.SerialDevice`. Now I have to export my code into a portable class library. In the pcl I have no access to any framework which grand me access to the serial port of my computer.

I've found this [article](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dsplaisted/archive/2012/08/27/how-to-make-portable-class-libraries-work-for-you.aspx). It says that I have to implement an interface in my pcl and write the code for accessing the serial port for each specific platform in an extra library. But I'm not that advanced in coding and I don't really understand how to do so.

Because of that I'm asking if someone has experience with accessing the serial port in an portable class library and can provide an easy way to do so? Maybe with UWP comes an easier way to realize this.

Comment: There's just nothing portable about that class.  The bigger picture is that PCLs will stop being relevant.  Because, you know, your app is *universal*.  Meanwhile, you'll have to use a normal class library.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but the thing is that it doesn't have to be a uwp app using this pcl. The target is, making it work with an winRT or WPF Application too.

Comment: Well, you discovered why it is not portable and PCL cannot work.  Not everybody is running Windows 10 yet.  Win7 is the new XP.  Wishing this problem away just won't get you anywhere, use SerialPort in the WPF app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot use Windows.Devices.SerialCommunication.SerialDevice in the Portable library directly. Because it is a platform specific API provided by Windows Runtime.

In this case, you can use the data model class to wrap the data object.

For example:

[image]